# Always getting 404 when running Spring Boot Gradle app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

**Edit: the root cause was a package structure + component scanning issue. I now have the main method class in `package com.example` and the controller in `package com.example.documents` and it is responding to HTTP requests.**

...

I'm setting up a simple Spring Boot app that can POST and GET for a /documents endpoint. I'm puzzled why I keep getting 404s when I hit anything on the server. When I'm in Postman and hit `localhost:8081/documents` or `localhost:8081/hello`, I always get 404.

I have a feeling I've screwed up the mapping, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've tried running with Gradle's `bootRun` as well as IntelliJ's built-in runner.

Console output doesn't show anything particularly interesting, just Spring components starting up.

```
<snip>
2021-01-25 17:01:35.067  INFO 13180 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-25 17:01:35.075  INFO 13180 --- [           main] j.Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application : Started Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application in 2.914 seconds (JVM running for 3.272)
our app is running...
```

Files:

**Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application.java**

```
package com.example.javaspringbootrestuploader2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("our app is running...");


    }
}
```

**DocumentController.java**

```
package com.documents;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class DocumentController {

    private final DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    DocumentController(DocumentRepository documentRepository) {
        this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
    }

    // Aggregate root
    // tag::get-aggregate-root[]
    @GetMapping("/documents")
    List<Document> all() {
        return documentRepository.findAll();
    }
    // end::get-aggregate-root[]

    @PostMapping("/documents")
    Document newDocument(@RequestBody Document newDocument) {
        return documentRepository.save(newDocument);
    }

    //one record
    @GetMapping("documents/{id}")
    Document one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return documentRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new DocumentNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

(There's some other files like `DocumentNotFoundException.java` but they're not very important to the question.)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its looks like a **component screener** problem on your project.

Spring Scan all component and add it own **Context path**, for component screening its looking component on the **Main class package** and its **subpackage**.

What is defined in here **group = 'com.example';**

Your DocumentController  component (Controller) is out of this package in this why Spring does not know about it and show 404.

**Solution:**

**One:**  Bring the DocumentController in 'com.example' package or in sub-package of 'com.example' package.

Like this:

```
    'com.example.documents';
```

**Tow:** Add an extra Component Screener Annotation on Main Class.

```
   @ComponentScan({"com.documents"})
```

Like this:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan({"com.example", "com.documents"})
    public class Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Javaspringbootrestuploader2Application.class, args);
            System.out.println("our app is running...");


        }
    }
```

It will be work.

Comment: I had a feeling it was a component scan issue, because I tried a CommandLineRunner class and it wasn't executing the commands. Let me try your suggestion later today, but I bet it's correct, and I will mark your answer as the solution if it works.

Comment: Thank you @Imranmadbar !

Comment: You're Welcome @AaronShaver